# Dropdown menu is only available when the parent is active

Tags: django, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, django-cms

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu which presents available blog posts. I noticed that, in order for the drop down arrow to appear, the "blog" node has to be selected. If I select any other node, then the arrow doesn't appear.

[Home Page - no drop down available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViQDT.png)

[Dropdown appears only when the blogs tab is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yr5w.png)

I'd like this to be laid out in a way which would allow users to open the drop down menu without having to go through the "blog" page. For example: a user could be on the home page, click on the dropdown, remain on the homepage, and then go straight to "blog 1".

Is this possible through Django-CMS?

This is the code that I'm currently working with:

```
from menus.base import NavigationNode
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from cms.menu_bases import CMSAttachMenu
from cms.models import Title

class TestMenu(CMSAttachMenu):

    name = _("test menu")

    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        n = NavigationNode(_('blog 1'), "/", 1)
        n2 = NavigationNode(_('blog 2'), "/bye/", 2)
        n3 = NavigationNode(_('blog 3'), "/hello/", 3)
        n4 = NavigationNode(_('blog 4'), "/hello/world/", 4)
        nodes.append(n)
        nodes.append(n2)
        nodes.append(n3)
        nodes.append(n4)
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_menu(TestMenu)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It's actually a problem with the way I coded the base.html. I originally ran it as:

`{% show_menu 0 1 0 100 "menu.html" %}`

I've now changed this to:

`{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "menu.html" %}`

More info can be found [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/navigation.html).